# Theory behind scroll spy jquery - Identifying the section under it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to work out how this might be done. I want to be able to identify which section I am in when scrolling through. This is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/AgBbK/embedded/result/

```
$(function () {

    var $select = $('#select');
    var $window = $(window);
    var isFixed = false;
    var init = $select.length ? $select.offset().top : 0;

    $window.scroll(function () {
        var currentScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        if (currentScrollTop > init && isFixed === false) {
            isFixed = true;
            $select.css({
                top: 0,
                position: 'fixed'
            });
            $('body').css('padding-top', $select.height());
        } else if (currentScrollTop <= init && isFixed === true) {
            isFixed = false;
            $select.css('position', 'relative');

            $('body').css('padding-top', 0);
        }
        //active state in menu
        $('.section').each(function(){
            var eleDistance = $(this).offset().top;
            if (currentScrollTop >= eleDistance) {
                var makeActive = $(this).attr('id');
                $('#select a').removeClass('active');
                $('#select a.' + makeActive).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });

    $(".nav").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var divId = $(this).attr('href');
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(divId).offset().top - $select.height()
        }, 500);
    });

});
```

The issue here is, the yellow bar has to be fully inside that section for me to be able to recognize that it is in that section and set it as active. For example, if the yellow bar was sat ontop of that section or 1px into it, I would still say that section is the active one, and yet the yellow bar must be fully inside it.

Is there any efficient and logical way to achieve this?

EDIT: As an example look how this must go all the way under the menu to know which section it is in: http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly don't get why you need a fixed menu for this purpose.

Here is a implementation of that example fiddle you posted that don't use any fixed elements.

It's way more responsive and it even have a mobile menu version for small screens.

#### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/vapuj/7/edit)